# Accept payments, pay people, automatically

Tags: paypal, payment, escrow

I am a new web-dev with what I think is a good idea. This idea requires handling payments.

I want to be able to accept a payment from user A, keep the payment for a set amount of time as an escrow, and then release the payment to user B's bank account after a set amount of time, and also charge a service fee, thereby reducing the amount paid to the bank account.. Occasionally, payments will need  to be refunded to user A. I want to integrate such payments into a website.

I want this to happen automatically, without having to handle each payment myself.

I have tried to find a service that does this, but the big ones that come to mind (Square, Paypall) don't seem to be set up for this.

Any suggestions of payment processing services would be appreciated. I am new to web dev – but feel free to be technical and I will figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal is indeed setup for this.  That's exactly what the sort of thing they introduced their [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) for back in 2009.

You can do what's called a delayed [chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id091QF0I30YK), which is where the buyer will submit the payment, and all the money will go to a primary receiver.  The money will stay there until you trigger the release of money to any secondary receiver(s) you might have on the transaction.

You'll use the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) to create the payment, and then you'll use [ExecutePayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/) to release the secondary payment(s) when necessary.